# Passing multiple or zero values in payload to call REST API using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, api, rest

How can I call post API with python using more than one or none values coming from DB instead of hard coding the values in my payload?
Meaning whenever I call post API, the payload value [id] can change according to the id or ids generated from SQL query.
When I hard code it and pass one value at the time in my payload it works:

```
dictionary={"profile_fields": {"name":["email", "address"]},"filters": {"id": "AB1"}}
```

But when I don't want to hard code it and use the variable name used to query my DB instead, I don't get any result back nor do I see any error.

```
dictionary={"profile_fields": {"name": ["email","address"]},"filters": {"id": 
               df}}
```

Thank you for your help.

**Sql output example:**

```
col1:
AB1
AB2
```

**Code sample Python 3:**

```
 c = con.cursor()

# sql query from sqlite, the output can be 1 vaue or two or even empty
c.execute('select col1 from t1 where col1 = col2')

df=c.fetchall()

print('checking the output of sql',df)

 #print output:
  # [('AB1',), ('AB2',)]

# data payload
dictionary={"profile_fields": {"name": ["email", "address"]},"filters": {"id": df}}

# url
url='https://...'
#post api call
response= response.post(url,json=dictionary,...)

 
if (responce.status_code == 200):
   #response back in JSON format
   df = response.json()
   print('Success!')
else:
  print('error.. ')
```

Answer (score 0):

> I don't get any result back nor do I see any error

This is strange, because result of `pd.read_sql_query` is a dataframe, while `fetchall` is a method of `cursor`. I am pretty sure it should not be there, and calling it would raise an exception.

Next thing, `df` is a dataframe, and is probably 2-dimensional, because you did not specify column in `read_sql_query`. Thus, you are sending array of arrays of `id`s. Try printing the payload to see what is being sent:

```py
print(json.dumps(dictionary))
```

Convert `df` to a collection of `id`s:

```py
ids = tuple(df[0])
```

Now, `ids` may be empty, it may be one or many values. How you deal with that is not in the scope of this question, but for now you can just `id = ids[0]` and put it into `dictionary` (instead of `df`).

Comment: Thanks Shadows. For simplicity I just removed data frame and used execute sql query instead. The main problem with my code is when my query returns more than one value, the post api call doesn't work. I did print the output of query and even seen the payload in my debug with two Ids passed on. But where I'm struggling is how to pass these two values or more to call post api.

Comment: @Joe if API you're communicating with does not support multiple `id`s then there is just no way to do this in one request. Try iterating over `id`s, doing 1 request per `id`.